# Why does XmlSerializer work on my singleton but not BinaryFormatter?

Tags: c#

I'm pulling my hair out trying to get my game save files converted from XML based to binary based. My GameManager class is a singleton. Loading and saving its instance variable using XmlSerializer works flawlessly, but when I try to use BinaryFormatter, I get an error that 'instance' isn't set to a reference of an object. 'instance' can't be null after a call to GameManager.Instance.LoadGame, since it's a singleton. If it was null, it would have been created when the method was called, right?

Here is the Xml version, that works fine:

```
        if (newText != null) {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GameManager));
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(newText)))
            {
                if (xmlSerializer.CanDeserialize(reader))
                    GameManager.instance = (GameManager)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
        }
```

Here is the Binary version that doesn't, I get an object not set to a reference on 'GameManager.instance':

```
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        GameManager.instance = (GameManager)formatter.Deserialize( stream );
        stream.Close();
```

I tried creating a setter for my Instance, which creates a new 'instance' if it doesn't exist, and the code will work without crashing, but the data isn't populated correctly, it's all empty when other parts of the game try to access it. If I create an entirely new GameManager object and populate that one, the data is populated correctly so I know it is getting serialized right, but my game doesn't work obviously because the data isn't where it needs to be.

Comment: Let me guess, your code/method using the BinaryFormatter throws some exception, and somewhere in your code you swallow that exception silently...

Comment: It's wrapped in a try/catch statement, and the catch statement is what spits out the error. I thought it might have something to do with the private static instance variable getting serialized along with the rest of the data, but that not happening with XmlSerializer,  but marking that variable as non-serializable didn't help any.

Comment: Show the code including the exception handling, please. I rather guess the BinaryFormatter throwing or returning `null`, since if your GameManager type is in an assembly (or your program executable) which you re-build constantly during your development process, BinaryFormatter will fail (as the serialized data includes assembly information which will not match anymore when you rebuild your project and thus let BinaryFormatter fail)

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. I was all ready to post the code when I realized I was still catching a generic exception instead of a SerializationException. The problem was that some of the non-serialized parts of my code needed to be rebuilt, they were causing the null reference, not instance. It would have taken me forever to catch that if you hadn't asked for the code, so thanks! If you can turn "use the correct exception you big dummy!" into an answer, I can mark it as the correct one. ;-)